# LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp download large file OOM

Tags: android, android-async-http

I need to download a large file from server using LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp in a android app,but got a OOM for the file is to large.
I have googled only to find that I need to write my own BinaryHttpResponseHandler and modify sendResponseMessage. But how can I do it? I am new in AsyncHttpClient. Can anybody give me some suggesstion?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure whether you are asking for this or not . Take a look at http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://example.com/file.png", new FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler(/* Context */ this) {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, File response) {
        // Do something with the file `response`
    }
});
```